# Getting rid of scaffold.css in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to get rid of the default css stylesheet app/assets/stylesheets/scaffold.css.scss but when I delete it and run the server the styles still seem to be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out your public ( or public/assets ) folder.  You may be serving a 'precompiled' version from public/stylesheets ( or public/assets ).  I think you can `rake assets:precompile` to update your file.  Vaguely remember having to do something like this when I was working with some code that someone else had configured the project.

Comment: Check out the following SO Question for information about cleaning the asset pipleline. [Difference between rake assets:precompile, rake assets:clean and rake assets:cleanup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335803/confusion-about-rake-assetsclean-cleanup-on-the-asset-pipeline-in-rails) - I believe this will help many to understand why these commands are used, concerning best methodology.

Answer (score 0):

Clean up your precompiled assets using:

`rake assets:clean`