# Rails asset pipeline - JS and CoffeeScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have both `.js` and `.coffee` files in my `/app/assets/javascripts/` folder.  The `.coffee` files will not run unless I call `rake assets:precompile`, which is a pain because I have to do `rake assets:clean` and precompile them again whenever I make a change.

Also, the precompiled .js file is included in addition to the source files, which causes double event handlers and all that good stuff.

My understanding is that the coffeescript should be compiled to javascript upon each request if it's not precompiled, but it doesn't seem to be doing so.  I can't find the compiled script loading in Firebug, and I don't see its behavior, at least.

My `/config/application.rb` has the following line configured:

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true
```

What else is there to check?

I am using Rails 3.2.3.

Answer (score 3):

> If you precompile on your local machine, then you can commit these generated assets into the repository and proceed with deployment. No need to compile them on production machine.
>
> But it introduces a problem: now when you change source files (coffescript / scss), the app won't pick up the changes, because it will serve precompiled files instead. rake assets:clean deletes these precompiled files.
>
> from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9335864/643500

What I usually do if I want the assets to precompile on the production server to pickup the new changes every build is just clean the assets - once of course unless you re-precompile them

```
rake assets:clean
```

When the changes are made and you don't want to precompile them every build do

```
rake assets:clean
rake assets:precompile
```